# .AspNetCore.Identity.Application cookie is set to session cookie when I add Additional Claims

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, identityserver4, claims-based-identity

I am using Identity Server4.

I am trying to figure out why my remember me button is not working, then I noticed that the problem lies with my additional claims, when ever the claims are added the identity cookie is set to session even if remember me is checked and handled like the code bellow

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LoginLocal(LoginInputModel model, string button)
    {
        // check if we are in the context of an authorization request
        var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(model.ReturnUrl);



        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberLogin, lockoutOnFailure: false); ;


            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation(1, "User logged in.");

                var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
                await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(user.UserName, user.Id, user.UserName, clientId: context?.Client.ClientId));


                var isuser = new IdentityServerUser(user.Id)
                {
                    DisplayName = user.UserName,
                };

                //the claims i'm trying to add
                isuser.AdditionalClaims.Add(new Claim("tenantId", user.TenantId.HasValue ? user.TenantId.Value.ToString() : 0.ToString()));
                isuser.AdditionalClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Email));

                if (model.RememberLogin)
                {
                    var props = new AuthenticationProperties
                    {
                        IsPersistent = true,
                        ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(AccountOptions.RememberMeLoginDuration)
                    };
                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(isuser, props);
                }
                else
                {
                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(isuser, new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = model.RememberLogin });

                }

        }

        // something went wrong, show form with error
        var vm = await BuildLoginViewModelAsync(model);
        return View(vm);
    }
```

I tried removing the claims and the functionality of the remember me button regarding the identity cookie whether it is set to session or persistent, is working fine

but without the claims I'll not be able to access my website which I'm trying to log in into

Any idea what the reason could be and how could I solve it

Comment: Can you share details of your IdentityServerUser class please? SignInAsync accepts a ClaimsPrincipal so I'm curious as to how this is working. What your'e doing with AuthenticationProperties looks correct and the behaviour should not be impacted by the claims you include in the payload.

Comment: here's the details of it after adding the claims:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GpJoQ4chThy2SjLcG-fj48MLHCYktXk0/view?usp=sharing